# Popcount Orders and Lexicographic Orders

Tags: boolean-algebra

A popcount order of a two bit vector {1,1}=3 can be given by:

{{1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1,    0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}}

and as a sequence of integers:

{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256}

We are basically just shifting bits...

A Mathematica code for it is:

HammingCycle[x0_] := Module[
  {x = x0, t = BitOr[x0, (x0 - 1)] + 1},
  out = BitOr[t, BitShiftRight[BitAnd[t, -t]/BitAnd[x, -x], 1] - 1]
  ]

where the input is an integer, for example 3 in the above...
The sequence is a lexicographic order as well.
Is it possible to get a function f(n) where I could get non-recursively a given value in the order? For example, f(5)=16...

Comment: The vectors and integers don't coincide! It is rather easy to generate $1,2,4,8,\dots$ (exercise). More generally, you want an encoding of ordered sets, using which you can generalize the exercise. Let us know if you're stuck.